# The External ID standard field vs custom external ID

Tags: custom-field, externalid, lightning-connect

I'm reading the lightning connect docs and I'm getting confused.
What exactly is External ID standard field?
I thought you can only define external id on custom fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects created for lightning connect are not custom objects and they are known as external objects .

External objects dont store data inside SFDC and they are just a metadata while the data actually resides in the external system .

> External objects have different standard fields.
>
> Display URL is the OData 2.0 URL representing a record in the external database, while **External ID is the primary key value for each record.**

For external object you will always have this standard external Id field auto populated from the source system

Comment: to cut the story short Standard External ID is reserved for SFDC field type on object (standard and custom) residing in Salesforce while the description external or custom external ID is meant for external objects. It's funny because I recall it from consultants exams where the names appeared in answers. (questions were about standard salesforce tables)

Comment: I'm not sure what is more confusing SF exam questions or the docs. Have a look at the external lookup section folks https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=external_object_relationships.htm "Parent Field for Matching Records" where parent is an external object - "The External ID standard field" external and standard at one. I'm giving up